# Cocoa NSAnimationContex Weird behaviour

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, caanimation

I have an `NSView` `NSButton` and an `NSTextField` in this view's subviews
all of them are Layer Backed
I ma trying to animate this view changing frame.

```
- (void)animateTheView:(SPTabView *)view toFrame:(NSRect)endFrame
{
    [NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context)
    {
        context.allowsImplicitAnimation = YES;
        context.duration = ANIMATION_TIME;//is a define 0.6f

        [view setFrame:endFrame];

     } completionHandler:nil];
}
```

**Edit** In my view I am not using AutoLayout I am just overriding the setFrame:

```
- (void)setFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    [super setFrame:frame];

    [_titleLabel setFrame:self.bounds]; //The NSTextField I am talking about

    [_closeButton setFrame:NSMakeRect(5, 2, B_WIDTH, B_HEIGHT)];//This one works fine

    [self removeTrackingRect:_tracking];

    _tracking = [self addTrackingRect:[self bounds] owner:self userData:NULL assumeInside:NO];
}
```

**EDIT 2** Posting the subViews Initialisation Code

```
[super setWantsLayer:YES];
[self setWantsLayer:YES];
[self setCanDrawSubviewsIntoLayer:YES];

[self drawRegular];

_closeButton = [[NSButton alloc]init];
[_closeButton setCanDrawSubviewsIntoLayer:YES];
[_closeButton setTitle:@"X"];
[_closeButton setTarget:self];
[_closeButton setAction:@selector(closeTab)];
[_closeButton setHidden:YES];
[_closeButton setWantsLayer:YES];

_titleLabel = [[SPLabel alloc]init]; //SPLabel is a silly subclass of NSTextField which just set it's properties like editable to as NO
[_titleLabel setText:@"Untitled.txt"];
[_titleLabel setTextColor:[NSColor blackColor]];
[_titleLabel setAlignment:NSCenterTextAlignment];

[_titleLabel setWantsLayer:YES];
[_titleLabel setTag:6];

[self addSubview:_titleLabel];
[self addSubview:_closeButton];
```

My view and it's button animating FINE! but the textField doesn't animate at all - it just jumps to the EndFrame...

Any Ideas some1 ?

Comment: Try putting `[view layoutSubtreeIfNeeded]` inside the animation block.

Comment: @jtbandes just tried, same behaviour

Comment: Where is the text field? A subview of `view`?

Comment: @jtbandes Yes Exactly :)

Comment: And are you using Autolayout? Can you put some more details / screenshots in the post?

Comment: @jtbandes I am not using AutoLayout, Edited the question

Comment: @jtbandes When I am not setting a layer to the textField - it does the moving animation, However the text is getting smaller/ bigger :)